# Gradle + TestNG Only Running Specified Group

Tags: java, gradle, testng

Trying to reorganize a very large library of tests by grouping them into different areas. What I've done so far is create a "api-crud" group within TestNG and setting the @Test parameters accordingly.

How can I, in gradle, run only these tests? When I try to do the following:

```
includeGroups 'api-crud'
```

gradle seems to run everything still.

I've seen some of the examples of setting excludeGroups, but that is currently unrealistic due to the size and scope of the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

includeGroups worked for me. Try running *gradle clean test -i*. Here is what I tested with:

**src/main/java/Greeter.java:**

```
public class Greeter {..}
```

**src/test/java/GreeterTest.java:**

```
public class GreeterTest {

    private Greeter greeter = new Greeter();

    @Test(groups = ("simple"))
    public void sayHi_default() {..}

    @Test(groups = ("personalized"))
    public void sayHi_with_args() {..}
}
```

**build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
version = '1.0'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile 'org.testng:testng:6.8.21'
}

test {
    useTestNG() {
        includeGroups 'simple'
    }
}
```

Comment: Tested with Gradle 2.1