# Executing specific testng group using build.gradle

Tags: gradle, testng, build.gradle

I have checked following questions but none of them helped -

[Gradle + TestNG Only Running Specified Group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28772744/gradle-testng-only-running-specified-group)

[Gradle command syntax for executing TESTNG tests as a group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49563007/gradle-command-syntax-for-executing-testng-tests-as-a-group)

The project I am using is available at - https://github.com/tarun3kumar/gradle-demo
It is standard maven project and I am not using testng.xml file.
Test method -  `com.org.corpsite.LandingPageTest` is grouped as - `smoke`

I am running test as - `gradle clean test` and test is executed. Test fails due to genuine reason and let's ignore it.

Then I passed test group from command line as -
`gradle clean test -P testGroups='doesnotexist'` 
Notice that 'doesnotexist' is not a valid group but it still executes test.

Following this I added `includeGroups` in `build.gradle` as -

```
test {
    useTestNG() {
        includeGroups 'smoke'
    }
}
```

and now `gradle clean test -P testGroups='doesnotexist'` fails with NPE on one of the java class - `java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.org.pageobjects.BasePage.findElements(BasePage.java:24)`

Questions -

1. What is right flag to specify test group from command line? Seems `-P` is wrong else `gradle clean test -P testGroups='doesnotexist'` would not execute test.
2. What is wrong with specifying `includeGroups 'smoke'`?

I am using `Gradle 5.1` on macbook pro

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here are the set of things that need to be done to get this to work.

1. You need to add the attribute `alwaysRun=true` to your `@BeforeMethod` and `@AfterMethod` annotations from your base class `com.org.core.SelTestCase`. This is to ensure that TestNG executes these configuration methods all the time irrespective of what group is chosen.
2. Alter the `test` task in your `build.gradle` to look like below:

```java
test {
    def groups = System.getProperty('groups', 'smoke')
    useTestNG() {
        includeGroups groups
    }
}
```

This ensures that we try to extract the JVM argument `groups` value. If its not specified we default to `smoke`.

We now execute the tests by specifying the groups needed using the below command:

```
./gradlew clean test --info -Dgroups=smoke
```

Now if we execute the below command, you would notice that no tests are executed.

```
./gradlew clean test --info -Dgroups=smoke1
```

Here's a patch that you can apply to your project

```
From 25133a5d2a0f96d4a305f34e1f5a17e70be2bb54 Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
From: Krishnan Mahadevan <krishnan.mahadevan@stackoverflow.com>
Date: Mon, 14 Jan 2019 22:38:27 +0530
Subject: [PATCH] Fixing the bug

---
 build.gradle                                | 2 ++
 src/main/java/com/org/core/SelTestCase.java | 5 +++--
 2 files changed, 5 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)

diff --git a/build.gradle b/build.gradle
index 10ba91d..2d08991 100644
--- a/build.gradle
+++ b/build.gradle
@@ -38,7 +38,9 @@ task smokeTests(type: Test) {
 }*/

 test {
+    def groups = System.getProperty('groups', 'smoke')
     useTestNG() {
+        includeGroups groups
     }
 }

diff --git a/src/main/java/com/org/core/SelTestCase.java b/src/main/java/com/org/core/SelTestCase.java
index 80cad09..651529a 100644
--- a/src/main/java/com/org/core/SelTestCase.java
+++ b/src/main/java/com/org/core/SelTestCase.java
@@ -22,7 +22,7 @@ public class SelTestCase {

     private WebDriver webDriver;

-    @BeforeMethod
+    @BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true)
     @Parameters({"browser", "url"})
     public void setUp(@Optional("firefox") String browser, @Optional("https://www.google.com/") String URL) {
         switch (browser) {
@@ -40,8 +40,9 @@ public class SelTestCase {
         webDriver.get(URL);
     }

-    @AfterMethod
+    @AfterMethod(alwaysRun = true)
     public void tearDown() {
         webDriver.quit();
     }
+
 }
-- 
2.20.1
```

You can save the above contents to a file say `mypatch.patch` and then apply the patch using the instructions detailed in [this StackOverFlow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2250170).

Comment: if we have more than one group name then ? I mean smoke & Sanity.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to run a specific test with the 'testInstrumentationRunnerArguments' flag:

```
-Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.class=com.abc.NameOfMyTestClass
```

Comment: I want to execute test group and test pertaining group might be spread across various classes. Also I it is not an android project (if it matters).